# bison parser basic questions

Tags: bison, lex, flex-lexer, parser-generator

I have some confusing question which make me run in a loop, please help me to understand them.

1. if I have two file one is `.y` which is the parser file and the second is the `.l` lexical analyzer 
   can I use the `yytext` in the parser file, should I define the `yylex` there to use it or not?
2. there is a default `yyerror` function if I want to change it should I declare it in the parser file in the section of the declarations?
3. if in the lex file I return a token to the parser something like this:

   [0-9]    return DIGIT;
   what is passed to the parser the DIGIT with the digit found or just the digit itself without the DIGIT?
4. how can I use `yylineno` in the parser file ,because I need the parser to use `yylineno` and tell where did the error happened and what token caused that?
5. in the parser file when I write a rule like this:

   exp -> exp |/*empty*/

is it the same as

```
exp ->/*empty*/ |exp
```

I appreciate anyone who could help me with those question because they had confused me,thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `yytext` in the `.y` file is dangerous and error-prone -- it's not well defined whether `yytext` is an array or a pointer, and it may not even be externally visible outside the `.l` file.
2. There's a `yyerror` function defined in liby.a -- if you link with `-ly` it will be available to you.  If you want to define your own `yyerror`, you can do so anywhere.
3. `return DIGIT;` will return `DIGIT` as the token (presumably a token defined in the `.y` file with `%token`, which has nothing to do with the actual digit value.  If you want to access the digit value in the parser, you need to copy it from `yytext` to `yylval` in the lexer:

   ```
   [0-9]        { yylval = *yytext-'0'; return DIGIT; }
   ```
4. `yylineno`, if it exists (requires the right flex option to have it created automatically) is generally just a global variable.  You need to be careful in that the parser may read ahead a token before reducing a rule, so `yylineno` may be off by that one token to what you really want.  If you're using bison, you can have your lexer copy `yylineno` into `yylloc` before retruning each token, which will allow you to get the correct line number for every token in the parser.
5. The following are all identical:

   ```
   exp: exp | /*empty */ ;
   ```

   ```
   exp: /*empty*/ | exp ;
   ```

   ```
   exp: /*empty*/ ;
   exp: exp ;
   ```

in general, order of rules in the `.y` file does not matter (it affects resolution of reduce/reduce conflicts, but nothing else).

Note that having a rule like `exp -> exp` automatcially make your grammar ambiguous and leads to shift/reduce conflicts.

Comment: first of all thank you Chris Dodd for your help, but there is a things that I didn't understand : the answer 3 is yylval just defined in te lex file and also defined in the parser file and what its type ,the same for yylineno and yyloc , and regarding the last rule you gave why it makes the grammar ambiguous ,if I got exp I will reduce why should I shift there is nothing else in this rule